# how to add two pictures in a single picturebox and display them simultaneously?

Tags: vb.net

i want to add a picture of a field like a football field and on it a ball would roll (just like the football). i have loaded the field's picture in the picturebox , but m nt able to load the second picture i.e of the ball. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Picturebox as container and simply add 2 other Pictureboxes to it

Comment: And play with the Anchor property.